# output of doParallel workers

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Suppose I have a code that does various calculations in a *foreach* loop, for simplicity let it be this:

```
foreach( idx = 1:10 ) %dopar% {
   set.seed(idx)
   smp <- rnorm(10)
   print( sprintf('Index: %d', idx) )
   print( cat(sprintf('Value: %f \n', smp[1:10])) )
}
```

The main idea of the code is that its output is written in such way, that the index is presented once, after which follows various results of the main code. It is then easy to read a log file and debug with such structure when using `%do%`, however with `%dopar%` the log file gets cluttered.

Question: *Without changing the code*, is there a way for each worker to create its own output file? I'm new in working with `doParallel`, so the only way of parallel output I've found so far is using the following:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4, outfile = 'log.txt')
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

However, `outfile` takes only a string as an argument, haven't found a way of passing a vector of names to it. So, maybe there is a way to specify an output file for each worker?

*NB: Working on Windows 7.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many solutions – like not using `print` in the workers or specifying the output file there – come to mind, but the question explicitly requests for *not changing the code*. I therefore assume that the code that's currently in the `%dopar%` body is wrapped in a function that cannot be changed:

```
doNotTouch <- function(idx) {
  set.seed(idx)
  smp <- rnorm(10)
  print(sprintf('Index: %d', idx))
  cat(sprintf('Value: %f \n', smp[1:10]))
}
```

One solution is to specify the output file directly *before* `doNotTouch` is called (or more precisely: execture the function in an environment where the output is redirected to a certain file):

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)


foreach(idx = 1:10) %dopar% {
  capture.output(
    doNotTouch(idx), 
    file = paste0("log", idx, ".txt"))
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

This doesn't change the code presented in the question but rather puts it in a wrapper that takes care of the correct output file `log_[idx].txt`.

**EDIT**: In the comments, it was clarified that the question is less about writing to separate files but rather about getting output that is not cluttered. In this case, `return(capture.output(doNotTouch(idx)))` could be used in the loop to collect outputs belonging together and returning them at once. Moreover, @Nutle found out that `Sys.getpid()` returns a worker's PID which can be used to write separate logfiles *by worker* (as oppesed to *by iteration*).

Comment: Thanks, `capture.output` seems to do the trick. However, one small problem I'm facing is having a large amount of indexes (hence a large amount of log files), which can be easily solved by an additional script concat'ing them to one file. Then again, maybe it is possible to put a workers ID instead of `idx`? I haven't found yet, but maybe there's a function something like `getWorkersId()`, that fetches a string, unique for a worker, who is currently doing the iteration? This way, with `append = TRUE` I would get (in my case) only 4 log files :)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to get the "worker ID". But this looks a little bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you *do not* want separate files but just a tidy output, what about `return(capture.output(doNotTouch(idx)))` in the loop body?

Comment: Indeed it seems a little like _XY problem_, sorry about that. Just in my case 4 log files were just as acceptable as 1 log file (as long as it wasn't 30 of them), so I didn't focus on that. `return` will probably be better, though I've also found that `Sys.getpid()` gets the worker's ID. Thanks again :)

Comment: Happy to help; after all I learned something myself. :) I'll update my answer later to include the `return(capture.output(...` and the `Sys.getpid()` solution.